# Automated unit tests when deploying Azure Web app using the portal

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, nunit

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution with the following structure:

```
Solution.sln
--- Solution/Main.csproj
--- Solution.Services.UnitTest/Solution.Services.UnitTest.csproj
```

For simplicity in this question, lets say my Main solution is both my website and services. So we have one solution with is the "application".

The UnitTest solution is a simple solution that refers the Main project, but with a lot of unit tests (using NUnit).

I have setup automatic deployment in Azure. Every time I make a commit on `develop` it updates one web-app, and when I update `master`, it updates another web-app. I've done this by setting up the integration to my Github repo here inside the Azure portal:

```
Webapp --> Deployment --> Deployment Options
```

**My question is: how do I run my unit test first?**

I don't see any options to add this. I don't see any option if I use the newer `Continious Delivery (Preview)` either.

I can see there is an option to add performance tests, but thatis not what I need.

So my question is two-fold: How do I add these unit tests inside the Azure web portal / updating my build file? And if this is not possible inside Azure, what is the "norm" on how to solve this (very common, I assume) problem?

Comment: Do you have deployment scripts? Consider editing the script to run your tests as part of the deployment. Check this article http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/enterprisedev/cloud/azure/azure-web-sites-deployment-and-unit-testing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom KUDU script to the root directory of your solution. At that point you have "complete" control over the build and deploy pipeline in Azure. Every web app has a default script in Azure. If you pull your current KUDU script (assuming your are using dotnet core), you should just need to add a `dotnet test` command before the `dotnet publish` command and fail accordingly.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script

If you have looking for a friendlier alternative, then you can use any number of CI/CD tools outside of Azure. VSTS offers several free build minutes every month.